# Extract text with any command in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

How do I extract the text from the following text and store it to the variables:

```
05:21-09:32, 14:21-19:30
```

Here, I want to store 05 in one variable, 21 in another, 09 in another and so on. All the value must me stored in array or in separate varibles.

I have tried:

```
k="05:21-09:32, 14:21-19:30"

part1=($k | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}')                                                                                                                      
part2=($k | awk -F"-" '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
part3=($k | awk -F"," '{print $2}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
part4=($k | awk -F"-" '{print $3}' | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
```

I need a more clear solution or short solution.

Comment: please show your attempts. Googling a bit would've shown you many good answers

Comment: D="2013/01/17"
DAY=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
MONTH=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
YEAR=$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')

echo "Day: $DAY"
echo "Month: $MONTH"
echo "Year: $YEAR"

Comment: @RaghulM that's not even close to a duplicate for this issue, other than a tangential reference to `grep` as a possibility.  The reference that you mention is about how to match known text in files, where this is how to split data into separate fields.  Nowhere close to the same thing.  I hope that you didn't vote to close based on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems.

- You can't pipe the value of `k` to standard output with just `$k` -- you want something like `printf '%s\n' "$k"` or perhaps the less portable `echo "$k"`
- Notice also the quoting in the expression above; without it, the shell will perform wildcard expansion and whitespace tokenization on the value
- Spawning *two* Awk processes for a simple string substitution is excessive
- Spawning a separate pipeline for each value you want to extract is inefficient; if at all possible, extract everything in one go.

Something like `IFS=':-, '; set -- $k` will assign the parts to `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, and `$4` in one go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read` with the `-a`rray option:

```
IFS=':-, ' read -ra my_arr <<< "05:21-09:32, 14:21-19:30"
```

The above code will split the input string on `:`, `-`, `,` and spaces:

```
$ echo "${my_arr[0]}" "${my_arr[1]}" "${my_arr[2]}" "${my_arr[3]}"
05 21 09 32
```